# How can I play the Mask of the Betrayer expansion natively on my Mac?

Tags: macos, neverwinter-nights-2

I'm reliving all games and I would like to play the mask of the betrayer expansion on my Mac, but although the initial campaign has been ported, Mask of the Betrayer seems it hasn't.
Please, no parallels, VMs or similar.

How can I play the Mask of the Betrayer expansion natively on my Mac?

Comment: Is "MAC" an abbreviation for something, or do you mean "Mac"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look [at this blog post](http://bbellina.blogspot.it/2011/11/getting-nwn2-expansions-working-on-mac.html).

It looks like you need Bootcamp anyway, with a Windows version of NwN installed there to transfer files.

There's also a torrent somewhere on the Internet that lets you play MoB and SoZ on the Mac, but I don't think it can be linked here.

Comment: @mvime glad to hear that. You're welcome